# How to reqeust using Http/2.0 in http library with DialTLS?

Tags: http, go, http2

i want to request with http library in Golang using http2, i tried almost everything and made a lot of research without any success so i am asking here if any one can help me and give me the right answer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    tls "github.com/refraction-networking/utls"
)


func main() {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://http2.pro/api/v1", nil)
    tlsspec, _ := ParseJA3("771,49195-49196-52393-49199-49200-52392-49161-49162-49171-49172-156-157-47-53,65281-0-23-35-13-5-16-11-10,29-23-24,0")
    transport := &http.Transport{
        DialTLS: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            conn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            host, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(addr)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            config := &tls.Config{ServerName: host}
            uconn := tls.UClient(conn, config, tls.HelloCustom)
            //tlsspec is just custom tls 
            if uconn.ApplyPreset(tlsspec); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if uconn.Handshake(); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            return uconn, nil
        },
    }
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to include "h2" in [tls.Config.NextProtos](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config.NextProtos)?

Comment: @KawaCode I tried your code and it does use `HTTP/2` for connection.

Comment: @Nick, did you try with tls.HelloCustom?

Comment: @Peter Yes, i did this `config := &tls.Config{ServerName: host, NextProtos: []string{"h2"}}`

Comment: Nevermind i got the solution